# Dynamically change URL in ajax json call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, url, dynamic

Forgive me I am new to javascript and ajax.  I tried searching for an answer to this, but cannot find everything I need.

I am calling a PHP page with json, and I want to be able to change the url in my ajax request when I click an anchor tag link.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'myphp.php?query=queryID',
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
success: function(result){

$(document).ready(function() {

  var innerimg = "";

for(var i=0, len = result.length; i<len; i++) {

//  much code here from json call

}   });


},
});
```

what I am looking to do is just change the queryID, from a simple onClick(), in an a href tag.

Answer (score 0):

Two things... If you are using something like `<a href="QueryID">` and attaching the event to the `<a>`'s click handler, it can be done something like this:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
  // Don't follow the links.
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myphp.php?query=' + $this.attr("href"),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
      // $(document).ready(function() {                // Remove this line.
      var innerimg = "";
      for(var i=0, len = result.length; i<len; i++) {
        //  much code here from json call
      }
      // });                                           // Remove this line.
    },
  });
});
```

Secondly, you don't need the `$(document).ready()` function there.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an event.preventDefault() to prevent an accidental page load

Comment: @Dais Sure... Updated.

Comment: @Dais Actually I am not doing anything related to it, but was mainly concerned about getting the data. Check out the question. `:)`

Comment: thanks for the quick response... i guess my problem is that i am not sure what to use to call it in the "a" tag

Comment: @Praveen: Thanks for updating. I understand, it was just a small note to prevent a possible page reload which would break the ajax call and your fix.